# unable to move a div to right which is creating dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons in my `div`, left side and right side. When I click on right button it need to move to right and for left button it need to move to left. I used:

```
           $('.left').click(function(e) {
                     $('#votersDetailsTable').animate({
                     'marginLeft': '30px'
                     });                
           });
```

can i use like

```
         $('.left').click(function(e) {         

             $('#votersDetailsTable').live("animate",{
            'marginLeft': '30px'
            });                
        });
```

Here `maindiv` is also creating dynamically .I am unable to move the div.Please help me.Thanks in advance..

Comment: So... what is the problem?

Comment: use on method of jquery. live is deprecated

Comment: i am using older version of jQuery

Comment: "It is not working" Well that's helpful! What isn't working? Does it make an error? Does it do nothing? Does it make the `div` disappear? Does it make flying monkeys appear out of nowhere?

Comment: [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, you should use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: no the div is not moving.I want to move my div to left but it is not moving\

Comment: Then maybe you could have put that in your question? How can we read your mind?

Comment: @Doorknob  i am really sorry.I forgot it

Comment: the div does not move, because every time the button is clicked, the left value is set to `30px`. you have to add the 30px to the current value like so: `left: oldleft+30`

Comment: ok actually my requirement is that.But it does not move to anywhere

Comment: From [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) "Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading += or -= sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property."

Comment: small sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v3QZv/ ... but without any html code, it's not easy to get to your specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put the div's position to `relative` in your css file

```
#mainDiv{
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry @Doorknob he is saying in his mysterious question that its not moving, if the position was not filled the `left` css attr is ignored.!!!

Comment: thanks a lot.It is working for me.I dont know why people will give downvote without any thinking

Comment: I'm glad that i could help sir,

Answer (score 0):

We'll need to see more of your css and html that contain these buttons.  However your issue is that you are animating the attribute `left` which will only do something if `#mainDiv` is positioned `absolute` (or `fixed`).

The attributes you can change inside `jQuery.animate()` are css attributes.  So you'll probably want `marginLeft`.

Generally when I have to create elements dynamically and then animate them, I write out the html / css for the before and after and find differences in order to figure out what attributes to animate.

Comment: i used this .But i dont need margin left i need to move the div

Comment: Can you share your html and css for the buttons, so we know what `#mainDiv` and `.left` are?

Comment: i am calling a method in onload then i used .html() to print that content

Comment: The method you get the html and css there shouldn't matter, so long as it ends up there the way you want it.  Can you update your question to include the html of your buttons, and the css that affects them?

Comment: wrong, ofc one can animate any css properties using jquery. see my provided fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v3QZv/

Comment: @Imperative `jQuery.animate()` can animate any css, sure, but it doesn't help to update `left` if the css attribute `left` would have no affect on the layout.

Comment: @PSR I updated your question to show what kind of information we'll need to help you out.  Fill that in with the actual html/css and we can fix this up really quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Put alert just before animate to check if control is coming into click function. If not 
try using `.on()` instead of `.live()`

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/zR72r/1/)

[Refer to MDN Docs for left css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/left)

`left` applies to only positioned element's

```
#mainDiv{
    position:relative;
}
```